# How to increase specificity weight

Tags: css, jsp

```
<td class>
     <div class="browser indicator">
     <div class="mobile indicator">
```

In this code, the class **indicator** has a *display:inline-block*. How do I increase the specificity weight of the class **browser** and **mobile** so I can give them a separate value for *display*?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by specifying both classes "chained", meaning `browser` when it has `indicator` as well use this style.

```
.browser.indicator {
  
}

.mobile.indicator {
  
}
```

The important part for you is to not have the space between the classes because doing this will style children with the class `indicator`

```
.browser .indicator {
  
}

.mobile .indicator {
  
}
```

Comment: I already did this, the weight is not enough and the display value from class indicator is still being used.

div.mobile.indicator {
}

div.browser.indicator {
}

Comment: @GeorgeMacarubboIII then you have other issues in your css structure. I suggest to update the question with a screen of the devtools to see what classes and styles that are applied.

Answer (score 0):

U can use this one:

```
.indicator {
 display:inline-block;
 width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .indicator {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

if screen size will be less **600px** all styles which u have at **@media** will provide for page.

Comment: I cannot do this as the class indicator is being used by other files also.

Comment: Then use id indicator